# Recoding values in second data frame based on values in a different data frame

Tags: r, recode

I want to recode the values in my second data frame based on the corresponding value in a different data frame.

for example, here's what the first data frame looks like. Each code is assigned to a corresponding zone.

| zone | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 |
| 2 | 23456 |
| 2 | 23457 |
| 2 | 23458 |
| 3 | 45678 |
| 3 | 45679 |

the second data frame looks like this:

| to_code | fr_code |
| --- | --- |
| 23456 | 12345 |
| 23457 | 23456 |
| 45678 | 23457 |
| 45678 | 23458 |
| 12345 | 45678 |
| 12345 | 23457 |

but I want to recode it based on the corresponding zones, so it would look like this:

| to_code | from_code |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the index of the matched 'code' from 'df1' with the values of the columns in df2 and extract the corresponding 'zone'

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df2 %>% 
   mutate(across(c(to_code, fr_code), ~ df1$zone[match(.x, df1$code)]))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df3 <- df2

df3[c("to_code", "fr_code")] <- lapply(df3[c("to_code", "fr_code")],
      function(x) df1$zone[match(x, df1$code)])
```

-output

```
df3
  to_code fr_code
1       2       1
2       2       2
3       3       2
4       3       2
5       1       3
6       1       2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(zone = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), code = c(12345L, 
23456L, 23457L, 23458L, 45678L, 45679L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(to_code = c(23456L, 23457L, 45678L, 45678L, 12345L, 
12345L), fr_code = c(12345L, 23456L, 23457L, 23458L, 45678L, 
23457L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: thanks for your response. i'm trying to use dplyr, it works, but I have several columns in my data frame and I want to apply it only to those two columns

Comment: @confusedpanda change the `across(everything()` to `across(c(to_code, fr_code)` (updated)

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following base R code using `match`

```
> df2[] <- with(df1, zone[match(unlist(df2), code)])
> df2
  to_code fr_code
1       2       1
2       2       2
3       3       2
4       3       2
5       1       3
6       1       2
```